# is there an auto-cage add-on?

Tags: add-on

I'm following a tutorial by Zacharias Reinhardt: "Mastering sculpting in Blender", and at some point we try to draw a cage around a dragon (see picture) 
[image]

In the tutorial, we do the cage manually.
I was wondering if there was an add-on or a technique to create such a cage automatically. Ideally, an add-on that would draw the cage around any selected object, with an offset option.

I tried this workaround but the results were terrible: copy the dragon, decimate many times until it's very low poly, then add a solidify modifier and adjust the thickness. The problem with this technique is that it doesn't create a cubic cage, but rather follows exactly the contour of the dragon, which create undesirable spikes at some locations (around the toes and the horns).

So is there such an add-on?